# How to find the second derivative (with respect to $x$) of $\cos y + \sin y = x$?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

How to find the second derivative (with respect to $x$) of $\cos y + \sin y = x$? The answer is $$\pm \dfrac {x}{(2-x^2)^{3/2}}$$

I dont understand how it goes from using just $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ to simple terms and a root. I've tried multiple times and have not gotten anywhere near the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you square both sides of the equation you get

$$\sin y+\cos y=x\implies\sin (2y)=x^2-1\implies y=\frac12\arcsin(x^2-1)$$

Now differentiate the last expression and find if you are missing some solution of the original equation. Note that $x\in[-\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2]$.

Comment: So I got the answer! But I only got a negative value, why is it +/- ? Because of the domain ? Also I was wondering how you knew to use the method that you had used, since it hadn't occurred to me to use that same method

Comment: @user639649 when you square you probably lose some set of solutions. I tried to simplify the LHS, and squaring it have a nice expression, this is why I did it

Comment: @user639649 also with the arc sine function you are reducing the solutions of the original equation

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can write $y$ explicitly in terms of $x$... up to a choice of branch for the $\arcsin$ function.

$$
\sin y + \cos y = x \Rightarrow (\sin y + \cos y)^2 = x ^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
\sin^2 y + 2 \sin y \cos y + \cos^2 y = x^2 \Leftrightarrow\\
\sin(2y) = x^2-1 \Leftrightarrow \\
y = \frac 12 \arcsin(x^2-1)
$$

Hence,

$$
y'(x) = \pm \frac 12 \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-(x^2-1)^2}}=\pm x (1-(x^2-1)^2)^{-1/2}
$$

Can you proceed?

Note that the relation does not globally define $y$ as a function of $x$... This is why we have the $\pm$, the "graph" would be a periodic function about the $y$ axis and when you pick a branch the function can be increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Ahh okay it makes sense, so does this mean that whenever you're being asked to derive a question that involves both x,y and cos and sin you should try and opt to write the equation explicitly and from then derive?

Comment: Sure, you can try to write y as an explicit function of x. If it works, fine, but it will normally not possible. In general, you should substitute y=y(x) in the equation, derive both sides and solve for y'(x). You will not get an explicit formula for y'(x) but a formula envolving x and y(x).